# How to bypass flash version check in linux firefox and use Gnash

Tags: linux, firefox, swf

Is it possible, and how, for Gnash to present itself as Adobe Flash to avoid "install Adobe Flash" messages while viewing flash-based websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pages still complain about missing flash plugin, it means you have not pointed your browser to the installed library. Once the browser is configured, Gnash should be used to work with Flash content... Only it has really big issues :/ From my own experience, I remember it was either crashing or not working with most pages.